# ng-show doesnt hide my element when value is set to false

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, ng-show

I am working on a web page that shows a certain piece of text and then hides it.  The show part is working, the hide part is not:

HTML

```
<div ng-show="uploadComplete" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Upload Complete</div>
```

Javascript

```
$http.post('/rest/upload-data', {msg:'hello word!'}).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(data + " " + status)
    $scope.uploadInProgress = false;
    $scope.uploadComplete = true;
    setTimeout(function() {$scope.uploadComplete = false; console.log($scope.uploadComplete);}, 3000);
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(data + " " + status)
    $scope.uploadInProgress = false;
    $scope.uploadFailed = true;
    setTimeout(function() {$scope.uploadFailed = false}, 3000);
  });
```

The label shows up correctly upon requesting the endpoint,

[image]

but it never goes away.  The console logs the set of the variable to false.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setTimeout doesn't trigger a digest. Use $timeout or $scope.$apply.

Answer (score 1):

The Angular equivalent of setTimeout is the `$timeout` service (see [here)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout).

Your syntax will be:

```
$timeout(function() {$scope.uploadFailed = false}, 3000);
```

Don't forget to inject it to wherever it is you're using it.

Try not to use `$scope.$apply` as it's better to let Angular handle the digest cycles unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the `$scope.$apply()` to set the `$scope.uploadComplete = false;` or even the `$timeout` of angular.